# Android: Reading raw data file with an asynctask

Tags: android, file

I currently need to read a lot of lines of data organized this way:

```
> *Name *IndexNumber *LocationA *LocationB *LocationC
> 
> 
> Barrel 4315124 2 3 43       > 
> car 414124 2 4 41           | 
> Red box 4315124 1 2 77      |--> actual file. 
> Glass cup 4515124 4 7 10    |
> Iron cup 4515124 4 7 9      >
> 
> ...
> --and so on---
```

What would be the best way to read it in an Asynctask? Thanks :)
 I know i need to use I/O stream, but i also know there are plenty of methods for reading data, so my question is what would be the best to use and how. :)

Comment: This is standard Java File I/O and will not change in an asynctask. What's the question?

Comment: For a column based system like this, why wouldn't you use a Database?

Comment: I don't know, why wouldn't I? O:...hehe, i don't know whats a database, i'll search it now. thanks :)

Comment: [SQLite Databases](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) is what I'm talking about.

Comment: it seems, overcomplicated.. I have found something named a Scanner, seems simple enough.